# Postgresql local database not working on my windows 10

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psql

so after installing postgres normally i tried connecting in the sql shell(psql) but an error kicks in immediately after putting in the username either the default or the new one,i tried checking if the postgres.conf file doesn't have listening_address='*' and port=5432 but everything was set up already in the file. I'm really confused because the tutorial i'm following did not have this issue,installation and usage was smooth,here's the error and all commands typed before the error itself:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]: 
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]: 
psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

and yea my firewall is not the issue cause i've turned off all firewall settings and still didn't work

Comment: this is not enough information to solve this issue. is there another program interferening with port 5432

Comment: What does the db server's log file say?

Comment: the last log message didn't give any specific message too that's why i didn't include it ```LOG:  could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.``` @jjanes

Answer (score -1):

If the log file entry you show is from earlier (and doesn't show up anew for each failed connection attempt) then you aren't even reaching the database server in the first place, so this is a networking issue not a database issue.

I've seen this with port forwarding, for example if there is a VirtualBox guest running that was configured to request port forwarding from that port on the host to the guest, but the program on the guest is not currently listening.  Then VirtualBox accepts the connection, realizes it doesn't know what to do with it so just immediately closes it, which leads to the client-side error you are seeing.  This is independent of whatever your firewall might be doing, so having the firewall turned off wouldn't change anything.  I've seen this specifically with VirtualBox, but would assume other port forwarding setups might exhibit the same behavior.

The firewall issues I have seen present differently.  They simply black-hole the connection, that is, drop it without acknowledging it or accepting it first.  This leads (eventually) to the client getting a time-out, rather than an unexpected close.

Comment: sincerely i can't wrap my head around a possible solution non of the tutorials i used faced this issue,i can't find similar issues on the internet

Comment: A long and technically correct answer doesn't offer even a hint of a solution. What is it for?

Comment: It is for not wasting time pursung phantoms.